# Copy Directory from Source to Destination depending upon selection

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I have implemented CopyDirectoryAndFiles functionality as below but it does not work correctly

Case - I want to copy/create `NAC -> NAC11 -> NAC12` (This is folder structure) from source to destination it only create/copy `NAC11->NAC12` 
I am passing source path as - `@"C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000001\20041202-01-0002-001\NAC` last part of it (\NAC) is chosen at run time from UI which folder you want to copy , it can be multiple folders as well, if i only pass path as `@"C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000001\20041202-01-0002-001` it copies everything from `src->dest`, but i want only selected one..how i can handle this situtaion in below code ?

```
Main() -

    copyDirectory(@"C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000001\20041202-01-0002-001\NAC"
,                 @"C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000005\20150622-1205-0015-M");

Method - 

    private static void copyDirectory(string Source, string destination)
            {
                string[] Files = null;           

                if (destination[destination.Length - 1] != Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
                {
                    destination += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
                }

                if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
                }

                Files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(Source);
                foreach (string Element in Files)
                {
                    // Sub directories
                    if (Directory.Exists(Element))
                    {
                        copyDirectory(Element, destination  + Path.GetFileName(Element));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Files in directory
                        File.Copy(Element, destination + Path.GetFileName(Element), true);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Your description is a little confusing.  Are you trying to copy the source structure to the destination or just the files in the specified folder to the destination? Should directory structures be preserved and copied over?

Comment: source structure to destination but depending on user selection so say user selected only one folder from source like NAC and it conatins (NAC->NAC11->NAC12) using my current code it only copies NAC11->NAC12 , NAC is not copied. directory structures be preserved and copied over (this is correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have the following source and destination directories specified:

```
var source = @"C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000001\20041202 - 01 - 0002 - 001\NAC";
var dest = @"C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000001\20041202-01-0002-001";
```

And you want to copy the `NAC` directory (along with all it's contents) from `source` to the `destination` directory, but the problem is that the contents of the `NAC` directory are getting copied directly into the `20041202-01-0002-001` folder, when you really want to end up with a path like the following (and this `NAC` directory should be identical to the source `NAC` directory):

```
@"C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000001\20041202-01-0002-001\NAC"
```

If that's the case, then you just need to first modify the destination directory path by adding the name of the source directory to it, like so:

```
destination = Path.Combine(destination, sourceDir.Name);
```

Here's a code sample that should do the trick:

```
private static void CopyDirectory(string source, string destination)
{
    var sourceDir = new DirectoryInfo(source);
    if (!sourceDir.Exists) throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(nameof(source));

    // Add last directory of source to destination and create it
    destination = Path.Combine(destination, sourceDir.Name);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);

    // Copy files from source to destination
    foreach (var file in sourceDir.GetFiles())
    {
        file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destination, file.Name));
    }

    // Recursively copy sub directories from source to destination
    foreach (var subDir in sourceDir.GetDirectories())
    {
        CopyDirectory(subDir.FullName, destination);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code gives me - C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000005\20150622-1205-0015-M\NAC\NAC11\NAC11\NAC12\NAC12 but it should be -> C:\TestArea\Destination\SUP000005\20150622-1205-0015-M\NAC\NAC11\NAC12

Comment: Oh, you're right...I was appending the name to the destination in the recursive call instead of letting the `CopyDirectory` do it for me, so it was doubling them up. I fixed that, so please try it now...